# Count duplicate value from table column using j query and show in new td as total duplicate value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html-table

Count duplicate value from table column using j query and show in new td as total duplicate value.
 i try this code but not see actual results.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var myarry =[];

var el = {};

$("tbody tr").each(function() {

    var row = $(this).nextAll();
    var first = row.find('td').eq(0).text();
    var second =row.find('td').eq(1).text();
    var third = row.find('td').eq(2).text();
    if(el[first + second + third]) {
        myarry.push(el);

    }else {       
        var c = (parseInt(myarry.length) + parseInt(1));

        console.log(c);

        row.find('td').eq(3).attr("rowspan",2);

        el[first + second + third] = 1;

        myarry =[];

    }


});
```

});

[image]

it should be dynamic .
I means to say table data will be change in future  some time there are 3 duplicate and some time 5 or etc.

Comment: already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60181834/count-duplicate-value-from-table-column-using-jquery-or-javascript-and-pass-to-r/60182355#60182355

Comment: Does this answer your question? [count duplicate value from table column using jquery or javascript and pass to rowspan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60181834/count-duplicate-value-from-table-column-using-jquery-or-javascript-and-pass-to-r)

Comment: not its not fulfill my requirements

Comment: What is the issue ?

Comment: if i change the data then count value will be random

Comment: according to your current screenshot it will work.. or you can post exact screenshot to get better answer @faizan